# Should I say I "post a post" on a forum?

Tags: word-usage

If I want to say

> I wanted to create new post (topic, question) but I forgot to do so.

should I say

> I wanted to post a post but I forgot to do so.

or should I say

> I wanted to post but I forgot to do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's theoretically correct, you just need to add an article to make a noun out of the word *post*, like this:

> I wanted to post **a** post, but I forgot to do so.

**EDIT:**

Either I didn't understand the question, or the others didn't understand my answer, so I'd like to rephrase myself: The above sentence is grammatical, there's nothing wrong with it from the technical point of view.

To go outside of what the OP asks, I would also add that repeating the same word is a bit unusual, but not incorrect. We don't know how the OP needs/wants to use the sentence, therefore we may not judge what's best for him.

To suggest some more usual options:

> I wanted to submit a new post.
>   I wanted to create a new thread.
>   I wanted to add my reply.

Comment: I think almost no-one would want to talk/hear about **posting a post**.

Comment: Which doesn't render the above sentence ungrammatical, now does it?

Comment: @Rimmer: No, but it may make it bad English.

Comment: The question is not whether the sentence is grammatical.  The question is how best to word the sentence.

Answer (score 5):

No. (!)  Like any other word, immediate repetition is bad practice. "I wanted to leave a post", or "I wanted to post an answer" would be fine. "I wanted to post" is not wrong, but could be confusing.

Comment: Immediate repetition is bad practice? What about past perfect "had had", for example? :) If only we had had more books at home when I was young ...

Comment: Still bad practice: 'had owned', or something similar depending on the meaning, would be more informative and less likely to lead to "'had had 'had had'" and the rest of it.

Comment: +1 because repetition of the word 'post' would be truly awful English. But *in context* I don't really see any problem with using "post" as an intransitive verb, so "I wanted to post" seems fine to me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher

Comment: @TimLymington: If you think *really, really* hard, you can come up with constructions where immediate repetition is commonplace.

Answer (score 2):

"Post a post" would be correct, however, you might be better choosing a different noun, because it does sound a little odd. You might say "post an article", or "post a blog entry", or "start a thread", or "reply on a thread", or simply "I wanted to post to the forum, but I forgot to." Your second suggestion of "I wanted to post but I forgot too" is also OK, but it does feel a little incomplete to me.

Answer (score 2):

“Post a post” is an example of [careless repetition](http://www.bartleby.com/116/501.html#10).  It's especially confusing because the repeated word is a different part of speech.  Technically, it's grammatical, but not every grammatical sentence is a good sentence.

Tim and Fraser give some good rewordings.